# Recompile source code to get .APK again

Tags: java, android

I have one compiled .APK and I  de-compiled it and modified the source code with my changes.
I want to compile it again with my new changes and get it back in the form of .APK.

Is it possible?

If yes, please help me.
Thanks.

Comment: are you able to build project using source code you got from APK file?

Answer (score 0):

No, Its not possible at all.

Once you have de-compiled your APK you can not compile it again and run it again to generate new APK.